# Persisting GroupState in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm using a framework that uses Apache Spark and stores agregations in the `GroupState`, using `mapGroupsWithState`

However, it is only stored in memory and when the server is restarted, everything is lost. The nature of the aggregations requires them to be long-lived, so I need to have them persisted (e.g. using the HDFS implementation in Spark)

I've read about checkpoints, but from my experiments they apply to datasets as a whole, which gets persisted, and in my case datasets are temporary and they update the GroupState, so it's the GroupState that is important to be persisted and then loaded.

The code looks something like this (simplified):

```
val df = loadNewDataFrame(..)
df.withWatermark(..)
  .flatMap {
     ....
  }
  .groupByKey {
    _.metric.internalKey
  }
  .mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout()) {
    updateGroupWindowState
  }
  .flatMap(x => x)
```

So, how do I persist the GroupState and then load it?